# Copy Files and Folders After Antivirus Scan

Tags: powershell, background, move, startup

I would like to run a PowerShell script on a Windows 2012 Server in the background at startup that does the following:

- Watches a folder and all subfolders (not a scheduled task; needs to be "live")
- Invokes a antivirus scan (if anyone is familiar with Symantec, I would like to utilize `DoScan.exe`)
- Copy files to a destination folder if they are "clean"; quarantine those that are not
- Log all activity

I have found bits and pieces of code and built a skeleton for this, but I am running into various issues. Firstly, PowerShell script quits after running for less than 10 seconds. Runs continuously in the ISE, however. Secondly, the `-WindowStyle Hidden` does not function as I hoped. I do not want the user to directly know the script is running. Thirdly (this may be more of a Symantec thing), my "invoke scan" routine seems to register as 1 big scan, instead of an individual file scan.

Any guidance is appreciated. Please explain why/why not this will work, and if I should use a different language, as well as if I should break this into more than one script.

```cs
$incomingfile = "E:\"
$filter = "*.*"

$watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $incomingfile, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters] 'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Even.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    foreach ($incomingfile in $watcher) {
        & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\DoScan.exe" /ScanFile $path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- There's a `t` missing in one of the statements of your watcher action:

  ```
  $changeType = $Even.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
  #                 ^^
  ```

  Shouldn't have an effect, though, since you're not using that variable anyway.
- The watcher only remains active while its parent PowerShell process is running.
- Your `foreach` loop is wrong. The watcher fires for each created file, so remove the loop and put the command directly in the action scriptblock.

  ```
  $onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent ... -Action {
      $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
      & "C:\Pro...can.exe" /ScanFile $path
  }
  ```
- Everything you want the script to do SEP can already do by itself. There's no need at all to re-implement the wheel with a `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there a way to keep the Powershell process running? It seems to quit in under 10 seconds and does not restart

Comment: Add an infinite loop at the end of the script: `while ($true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}`. And just to re-iterate: SEP can already do everything you want by itself. Without any line of PowerShell.